# I have an old blockchain wallet and a .txt file of 43 words, but the site wants 12 words?

Tags: blockchain, wallet-recovery

I have a wallet.aes.json file and a .txt file that contains 43 random words. They were both made within minutes of each other back in early 2014, and my confirmation emails from blockchain are also within minutes of these file timestamps. I also have a wallet ID from blockchain. Blockchain wants a recovery phrase of 12 words, and won't accept my 43 word phrase. I'm not sure what I can do to translate these 43 words into something that will let me into this wallet.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You can input legacy phrases here

https://login.blockchain.com/wallet/forgot-password

It spits out your password and wallet ID. I logged in. It's an empty wallet :(